# TLS connection to Melpa.org hanging on prelude

Tags: package-repositories, prelude, gnutls

I've enabled some new packages in bbatsov's prelude and when I restart the emacs daemon, it hangs endlessly starting up showing this:

```
Prelude is powering up... Be patient, Master g!
Loading personal configuration files in /Users/g/.emacs.d/personal/preload...
Loading Prelude's core...
Loading /Users/g/.emacs.d/savefile/recentf...
Loading /Users/g/.emacs.d/savefile/recentf...done
Loading Prelude's modules...
Loading /Users/g/.emacs.d/prelude-modules.el (source)...
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
Opening TLS connection to `melpa.org'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 melpa.org'...
```

What's the problem exactly? I can access `https://melpa.org/` without any problems.

Any workarounds?

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got around this by first starting emacs with `emacs --insecure` and once that worked and downloaded and what it needed, I was able to start `emacs --daemon` fine.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, I solved the problem by starting Emacs with the admin prompt (seems that admin rights matter). Also, you should check on whether gnutls is properly installed, following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950871/failed-to-download-melpa-archive