# Emacs daemon hangs on first run on Emacs 25.2

Tags: daemon, emacs25

I've installed Emacs 25.2 on Mac High Sierra Beta. I used it together with bbatsov's prelude.

When I first run `emacs --daemon`, it hangs showing this output:

```
m15:~ g$ emacs --daemon
Prelude is powering up... Be patient, Master g!
Loading personal configuration files in 
/Users/g/.emacs.d/personal/preload...
Loading Prelude’s core...
Emacs Prelude is now refreshing its package database...
ad-handle-definition: ‘ido-completing-read’ got redefined
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80
Type C-x 1 to delete the help window, C-M-v to scroll help.
Continue connecting? (No, Session only, Always) Always
```

Any idea how to debug this further? What is going on?

I've tried a few times and no matter what I enter as answer, it does the same. Nothing is taking CPU, nothing is being downloaded...

**NOTE**: I've installed Emacs via `brew cask install emacs`

Comment: Is it only the first time you try this that it hangs, or is it every time you try it that it hangs?

Comment: I've tried a few times and seems to hang every time.

Comment: Then please edit your question to make this clear. Currently it says that it hangs "on first run" etc.

Comment: What difference would have that made? :?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a slightly similar issue before (see [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20477/tls-connection-to-melpa-org-hanging-on-prelude)). I've tried the workaround and it worked.

So, if daemon ever hangs after changing things or first time you run, run `emacs --insecure` first, then `emacs --daemon`